# Serva Login 0x35 NetPath not found, wrong credentials, or unreliable net

Tags: networking, operating-systems

I'm trying to install Windows 8 via PXE network boot, I'm using Serva for this.

When I get to the ServaPENet screen on my client I can't connect. Drivers are installed (I tried three different drivers, all should be working), I tried several usernames and passwords (I changed it a few times to make sure it was not due to special characters). All should be working but I still get

```
    0x35 NetPath not found, wrong credentials, or unreliable net.
```

My server is a laptop connected via wifi and my client is a pc connected via lan.

WIA_WDS is shared as WIA_WDS_SHARE and my server user has access to read. I might have done something wrong in this step, but I also tried several solutions. Can someone give me a step by step tutorial to share this folder correctly?

Answer (score 0):

error 0x35 is explained on Serva's website

http://vercot.com/~serva/an/WindowsPXE1.html#troubleshooting

> 8.4.3 WDS OSs ServaPENet login ERROR:0x35:
>
> Microsoft defines error 0x35 (53) as ERROR_BAD_NETPATH and is supposed
>   to mean "The network path was not found" but in fact it really means a
>   lot more things.
>
> The error can be triggered in several ways: 1) Network connection
>   unreliable. 2) WIA_WDS_SHARE bad configured. 3) WIA_WDS_SHARE running
>   on a very busy/slow/unresponsive server. 4) NIC not working properly.
>   5) NIC driver not working properly (even if there are no errors). 6)
>   Wrong login credentials. If your network and server are ok I would
>   recommend checking the NIC and specially its driver.
>
> There were reported 0x35 errors when installing Vista while the same
>   client installed Windows 7/8 correctly. On all those cases: 1)
>   Replacing Vista's \sources\Boot.wim with Windows 7/8
>   \sources\Boot.wim. 2) Erasing Vista’s *SERVA* directory. 3) Quit and
>   restarting Serva. Solved the problem.

In these cases your best bet is start by checking the net driver **even if it looks like  working ok**

Comment: Yeah, but nothing there helped me. Everything was fine.. I ended up restarting the server computer, then tried again. Worked the first try. Apparently it had something to do with me changing the password all the time. Also, Serva didn't really like to try again if I had entered the wrong password once, even if I tried again with the correct one, it wouldn't work. I had to get it right on the first try but I didn't realize that, obviously. Thank you anyway.